# Dynamic OpenIdConnectOptions for multi-tenancy in Asp.net Core 2.1-*

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-security

I am working with aspnetcore v2.1 (latest dev branches) in order to create a multi-tenant app where each tenant authenticates against their own Azure B2C AD tenant. This aproach was chosen so that email/password selections and social login associations are unique per-tenant.

Instead of a static ClientId applied in Startup.ConfigureServices, I want to apply the correct ClientId and Authority based on the current tenant identity (which I determine based on the hostname).  Based on previous inspection of the 2.0-* code, I had been using an IOptionsSnapshot to allow me to apply the correct options as shown below.

In Startup.ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddSingleton<IOptionsSnapshot<OpenIdConnectOptions>, OpenIdConnectOptionsSnapshot>();
services.AddAuthentication().AddCookie().AddOpenIdConnect();
```

In Startup.Configure:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

With an implementation of :

```
public class OpenIdConnectOptionsSnapshot : IOptionsSnapshot<OpenIdConnectOptions>
```

However, now I find that my OpenIdConnectOptionsSnapshot is no longer being instantiated or referenced.

What is the correct way to apply a dynamic per-tenant ClientId, Authority, etc under AspNetCore Security 2.1.0-*?

(I am open to "you're doing it completely wrong" and suggestions of different ways to achieve multi-tenancy for tenants that have no pre-existing AzureAD footprint)

Comment: As a side note, I'd recommend voting for first class multi-tenant support in Azure AD B2C: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/9849063-aadb2c-how-to-on-multi-tenant-applications-based

Comment: done - thanks for the pointer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using IOptionsMonitor instead, we changed how IOptionsSnapshot worked fairly late in 2.0 and switched auth over to use the monitor instead.

[OptionsSnapshot is now scoped](https://github.com/aspnet/Options/issues/217)